# Wait for asynchronous operation inside Espresso test

Tags: java, android, automated-tests, android-espresso

I have `espresso` test for `Android`:

```
        @Test
        public void ExternalBankAccountDetailsFragment_InfoShown() throws InterruptedException {

            // SETUP
            mockRequest();
            clickOnItem();
mActivityRule.getActivity().setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE);

            Thread.sleep(100);

            // CHECKS
    onView(withId(R.id.view)).check(matches(hasDescendant(withText("test"))));
        }
```

And I need to use `Thread.sleep` to wait the `async` call. But I know that this is not a good practice. I'm familiar with `IdlingResources`, but I can not use it because I have to change my code to use it (for ex. `CountingIdlingResource` usage inside `callback` etc). 
How can I avoid usage of `Thread.sleep`()?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the end all solutions will do something like `Thread.sleep`. The question is: *How can you only wait for the minimum required amount of time?*

One alternative to Idling Resources is this tiny `ConditionWatcher` library:https://github.com/AzimoLabs/ConditionWatcher

You can create an `Instruction` that waits checks if the current activity can find a view example